# How to change the order of the form field when it is sorted in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to change the order of the form field in the table when the user sorts it in the dropdown menu. Basically, it will be in the uppermost left of the table when the user sorted it

the original table:

[image]

the table will look like this when the user sorted it in `name` field:

[image]

in my `forms.py` i have the field in order of:

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:

    model = myModel

    fields = [    
            "email",
            "name",
            "order",
         ]
```

and in my `models.py`:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
   role = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

my template.html:

```
{%for items in qs %}
<tr>

        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'crud-view' items.id %}">View</a>
            |
            <a href="{% url 'crud-update' items.id %}">Edit</a>
            |
            <a href="{% url 'crud-delete' items.id%}">Delete</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{items.email}}</td>
        <td>{{items.name}}</td>
        <td>{{items.role}}</td>
```

in my `views.py` i tried:

```
qs = myModel.objects.all().order_by("name")
```

but it is just sorting the items inside the `name` field. how can I make it so that the `name` field will appear at the uppermost left part of the table?

Comment: What is the code that generates the table?

Comment: @dyve i have edited it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using [django-django-tables2-column-shifter](https://github.com/djk2/django-tables2-column-shifter)

Comment: OK, it would have helped if I'd known you were using django-tables2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order_fields` method to achieve that.

```
self.order_fields(sorted_fields)
```

Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.order_fields